# Получение аргументов командной строки

Tags: c++, ассемблер, fasm

Надо получить аргументы командной строки используя FASM, я делал это так:

```
start:

mov ebx, DWORD [ebp+4]

invoke MessageBox, 0, ebx, window_name, MB_OK
```

передаваемый аргумент - test , а я получаю пустое окно. Пробовал смещения и 0 и 4 и 8.
При использовании:

ebp+0 - мя

ebp+4 - й)O ***тут еще символ 127-ой по счету в ASCII***

ebp+8 - ничего нету.

Я верно понимаю что необходимый параметр это ebp+4, но что-то не то с кодировкой? приложение -  32bit, ОС - 64bit

Comment: *"Я верно понимаю что необходимый параметр это ebp+4"* - нет, с чего вы это взяли? Для получения команды используйте [GetCommandLineW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew)

Comment: @user7860670, а если использовать чистый fasm без API. И передачу через стек?

Comment: Никак. А чтобы использовать передачу через стек, необходимо, чтобы через него кто-то передавал.

Comment: @user7860670 так когда мы запускаем exe с параметром командной строки, там внутри происходит вызов Main с параметрами, как обычного метода, а передача аргументов происходит через конвенцию вызова stdcall (справа на лево через стек)

Comment: Если запускать С++ приложение, то точку входа main со всеми параметрами предоставляет CRT runtime.

Comment: @War_Never_Changes, подтверждаю, ничего само по себе не происходит. Либо через GetCommandLine, либо собрать в объектный файл с экспортируемой функцией `_main`, потом слинковать как будто это сишный объектный файл со стандартной библиотекой Си, тогда кусок прилинкованного кода будет вызывать вашу _main с параметрами из параметров командной строки. Но в вызывающем коде все равно будет GetCommandLine.

Answer (score 0):

При запуски процесса система ничего не передает ему по умолчанию, если ты хочешь прочитать командную строку то ты вызываешь метод [GetCommandLineA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea) и он вернет тебе указатель нам командную строку. Дальше делай с ней что хочешь.

Параметры передаваемые в С++ на самом деле получается путем добавления к твоему коду дополнительного кода не видимого тебе который выполняет эту работу.